# How to have independent columns without sub-level

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have the following data:

[image]

I would like the data transformed to the following format:

[image]

When I tried to use a Pivot Table it uses the sub-level mode, i.e when calculating `hascycle` in the above scenario, it will calculate it based on `hascar`. I want them to be independent, only depending on the `portfolio` column.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I use PowerQuery unpivoted columns first and then created the PivotTable:

[image]